# Hoare logic trouble

Tags: logic

I'm trying to prove, using hoare logic, that $$\{true\}  w \{X=Y\}$$

where

[image]

---

I started with a bottom-up approach like so:

[image]

---

The actual solution is similar but diverges by saying $true\wedge X>Y\Rightarrow true$. How does that work???

The solution author refers to the **c**ontents of the while loop (the if-block) with $c$

[image]

Comment: Note that the negation of $X > Y$ is not $X < Y$.  If you are only proving partial correctness, it's just that **if** the loop terminates, the loop condition must be false.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Consequence rule. From the outer while loop we already know $X\neq Y$

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Also I understand that. `true∧X>Y⇒true. How does that work???`

Comment: As @FabioSomenzi alludes to, the fragment is trivially correct, either it terminates with $X=Y$ or it does not terminate. You need to demonstrate that the loop terminates. It might be easier to instrument the loop (add $i=i+1$ sort of thing) and reason in terms of $\Delta=X-Y$.

Comment: @copper.hat I understand that. `true∧X>Y⇒true. How does that work???`

Answer (score 1):

This is just an elaboration of Fabio's comment above:

To prove $\{ \operatorname{true} \} w \{ X=Y\} $, use a trivial application of While:
$\frac{\{P \land C\}S\{P\} }{\{P\}\operatorname{while} C \operatorname{do} S\{ P \land \lnot C \}} $, with
$P=\operatorname{true}$ and $C=X \neq Y$ since $P \land \lnot C = (X=Y)$. It does not
matter what $S$ is.

A small amount of additional work is needed to prove that $w$ terminates, but this is not
needed to prove the statement in the question.

Here is an outline of one way to prove finite termination. This is not a particularly illuminating approach:

First let $\Delta = X-Y$ and define $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ by
$f(\Delta) = \begin{cases} \Delta+1, & \Delta \le -2 \\
0,& x \in \{-1,0\}\\
\Delta-2, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$.

Let $\nu(X), \nu(Y)$ be the updated values of $X,Y$ defined by the $\operatorname{while}$ loop.

Prove that $\nu(X)-\nu(Y) = f(X-Y)$.

This suggests $|X-Y|$ as a variant function, but unfortunately the function
is not strictly decreasing when $X \neq Y$. This can be remedied by a hack;
let $\phi(x) = \begin{cases} |2x|, & 0 \le x \\
|x|, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Prove that if $X \neq Y$, then $0 \le \phi(\nu(X)-\nu(Y)) =\phi(f(X-Y)) < \phi(X-Y)$ (cf. Lyapunov function).

Comment: How do you prove it terminates? And why do you think the solution author went to the trouble writing the whole thing if you could simply just apply 1 (the while) hoare rule

Comment: Termination is a different question, but not difficult (it must terminate in $|X-Y|+1$ iterations). I cannot speak to the author's approach, I presume she was going to lead into proving termination?

Comment: Actually, if I was to hazard a better guess, I would imagine it was to force you to find a non trivial variant (since if $X-Y$ is odd and positive then the value of $|X-Y|$ does not strictly decrease with each iteration).